# c# How delete txt file 1st line?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, web-applications, webbrowser-control, c#-5.0

textbox4.Text already show .txt file 1st word.

Now I need how going delete 1st word from .txt file?

my code

```
    StreamReader objstream = new StreamReader("E:\\lastname.txt");

      textBox4.Text = objstream.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("E:\\lastname.txt");
File.WriteAllLines("E:\\lastname.txt", lines.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of: [Removing the first line of a text file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008542/removing-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-in-c-sharp).

Please someone close this.